# How to change border-radius of mat-button-toggle

Tags: css, angular

I have mat-button-toggle and want to change the `border-radius` to `20px`, but it is still `4px`.

What i do wrong?

```
<mat-button-toggle-group class="ruleActionOnOffButton" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" *ngIf="modules.type === action.type && modules.id === action.id" value="{{action.action}}">
  <mat-button-toggle value="1" (change)="selectionChanged($event,i)">An</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="2" (change)="selectionChanged($event,i)">Aus</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle value="3" (change)="selectionChanged($event,i)">Toggle</mat-button-toggle>
</mat-button-toggle-group>
```

**Css**

```
/deep/ .mat-button-toggle-group-appearance-standard, .mat-button-toggle-standalone.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard{
        border-radius: 20px !important;
    }

    .ruleActionOnOffButton .mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard .mat-button-toggle-label-content{
        border-radius: 20px !important;

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`:host`](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/) and `.mat-button-toggle-group`

```
:host .mat-button-toggle-group{
    border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

[See working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-toggle-ne1a4l?file=app/button-toggle-exclusive-example.css)

Comment: Did you see my example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-toggle-ne1a4l?file=app/button-toggle-exclusive-example.css that what you mean?

Comment: sorry... i added the css in the global css, not in the component.css... It working!!: :) thx

Comment: @לבנימלכה In your example why you're using `:host` & not `.ruleActionOnOffButton` directly which also works?

Comment: mat-button is an host DOM on the component which means need to use `:host` (maybe back in time(version of Angular) that was the best solution )

Answer (score -1):

If you like to change the border appearance of a single toggle button you can adjust it within the `styles.scss`:

```
// This will adjust the hover background of the toggle button to look like a material button:
.mat-button-toggle.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard:hover { 
border-radius: 4px !important; }

// And this will keep the background when the button is pressed:
.mat-button-toggle-checked.mat-button-toggle-appearance-standard {
border-radius: 4px !important; }
```

Side note: I have noticed that the animation, when the button is clicked, is still rectangular. I think this also adjustable, but you'll only see it when you zoom in.